# Formula for $1! \times 2! \times \cdots \times n!$?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, factorial

Are there any useful forms for the expression $1!\cdot 2!\cdot 3!\cdot ...\cdot n!$? I'm trying to solve a problem that involves this expression and thought it might help to find a more "workable" form for it, but I didn't get very far.

Thanks

Comment: What form is useful depends on context.  What would make a formula useful for you?

Comment: See [hyperfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html).

Comment: There is a closed form in terms of $\psi^{(-2)}(x)$, I think, but you probably haven't heard of that yet.

Comment: (Actually, that might not be true. I'll need to look in to it more.)

Answer (score 13):

In the May 2013
Fibonacci Quarterly
(Vol. 51, Num. 2)
pages 163-173,
Michael Hirschhorn
proved this result:

Let
$P(n)
=\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}
$.
Then
(this is going to be a pain to enter),
as $n \to \infty$,

$$P(n)
\sim C^{-1}\dfrac{e^{n(n+2)/2}}{n^{(3n+2))/6}(2\pi)^{(2n+1)/4}}
\exp\left(-\sum\limits_{p \ge 1}\dfrac{B_{p+1}+B_{p+2}}{p(p+1)}\dfrac1{n^p}\right)
$$
where
$$C 
=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{n^{1/12}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(
\dfrac{k!}{\sqrt{2\pi k}(k/e)^k}
\right)
\approx 1.046335066770503
$$
and the $\{B_p\}$
are the Bernoulli numbers,
defined by
$$
\sum\limits_{p \ge 0}
B_p \dfrac{x^p}{p!}
= \dfrac{x}{e^x-1}
.$$

I will now try to use this
to get an estimate for
$f(n)
=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n} n!
$.

Since
$P(n)
=\dfrac{(n!)^{n+1}}{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n} (n!)^2}
$,
$f(n)
=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n} n!
=\sqrt{\dfrac{(n!)^{n+1}}{P(n)}}
$.

I will now try to get
an estimate for $f(n)$
from the first term
($p=1$)
in the asymptotic formula
for $P(n)$..

Since
$B_2=\frac16$
and $B_3=0$,
$B_2+B_3=\frac16$,
so,
setting $p=1$
in the formula for
$P(n)$,

$\begin{array}\\
P(n)
&\sim C^{-1}\dfrac{e^{n(n+2)/2}}{n^{(3n+2))/6}(2\pi)^{(2n+1)/4}}
e^{-1/(12n)}\\
&\sim C^{-1}\dfrac{e^{n(n+2)/2}}{n^{(3n+2))/6}(2\pi)^{(2n+1)/4}}
\\
\end{array}
$

since that
$e^{1/(12n)}$
term goes to $1$.

Therefore
$\dfrac1{\sqrt{P(n)}}
\sim C^{1/2}\dfrac{n^{(3n+2))/12}(2\pi)^{(2n+1)/8}}{e^{n(n+1)/4}}
$.

Since
$n!
\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left( \dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n
$,
$(n!)^{(n+1)/2}
\sim (2\pi)^{(n+1)/4} n^{(n+1)/4}\dfrac{n^{n(n+1)/2}}{e^{n(n+1)/2}}
=  \dfrac{(2\pi)^{(n+1)/4}n^{n(n+1)/2+(n+1)/4}}{e^{n(n+1)/2}}
$.

Therefore,

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n} n!\\
&=\sqrt{\dfrac{(n!)^{n+1}}{P(n)}}\\
&\sim \dfrac{(2\pi)^{(n+1)/4}n^{n(n+1)/2+(n+1)/4}}{e^{n(n+1)/2}}
 C^{1/2}\dfrac{n^{(3n+2))/12}(2\pi)^{(2n+1)/8}}{e^{n(n+2)/4}}\\
&= C^{1/2} \dfrac{(2\pi)^{(n+1)/4+(2n+1)/8}n^{n(n+1)/2+(n+1)/4+(3n+2)/12}}{e^{n(n+1)/2+n(n+2)/4}}\\
&= C^{1/2} \dfrac{(2\pi)^{(4n+3)/8}n^{n(n+1)/2+(6n+5)/12}}{e^{n(2n+2+n+2)/4}}\\
&= C^{1/2} \dfrac{(2\pi)^{(4n+3)/8}n^{n^2/2+(12n+5)/12}}{e^{n(3n+4)/4}}\\
&= C^{1/2} \dfrac{(2\pi)^{(4n+3)/8}n^{n^2/2+(12n+5)/12}}{e^{3n^2/4+n}}\\
&= C^{1/2} \dfrac{(2\pi)^{(4n+3)/8}n^{n^2/2+n+5/12}}{e^{3n^2/4+n}}\\
&= C^{1/2} (2\pi)^{3/8}n^{5/12}(2\pi)^{n/2}(n/e)^n
\left(\dfrac{n}{e^{3/2}}\right)^{n^2/2}\\
\end{array}
$

(Yep,
that definitely *was*
a pain to enter.)

As usual,
since the math was done
as it was entered,
prob(no error) < .5.

Comment: I get the same $n^{n^2/2}$ as well as the same leading exponent of $e$ (i.e. $e^{-3n^2/4}$), but we differ on the linear terms in the exponents. I could easily have made a mistake as well.

Comment: Yep. I find it annoyingly easy to make mistakes in these types of computations. I am pretty sure that I transcribed Hirshhorn's results correctly (I really admire his work!), but my work is less likely to be correct.

Comment: Oops - I see an error in my transcription! I'll fix it up. Oy.

Comment: Up vote for effort!

Comment: Yes, that's a nice result of Hirshhorn! Your formula $\prod_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \prod_{k=1}^n (k!)^2 = (n!)^{n+1}$ is neat; I used $\prod_{k=1}^n k^k \prod_{k=1}^n k! = (n!)^{n+1}$. Our results are closer now, at least. :)

Comment: This is just an approximation, though, right?

Comment: @columbus8myhw Yes, $f(n) \sim g(n)$ [is the statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_formula) $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n)/g(n) = 1$.

Comment: BTW, that formula is Hirshhorn's, not mine. I advise you to look up his work - I'm a big fan of his. He is even referenced seven times in "Number Theory in the Spirit of Ramanujan" by Berndt.

Answer (score 7):

A posibble form is: $$\prod_{i=1}^ni!$$

In other way is $$1^n\cdot2^{n-1}\cdot3^{n-2}\cdot\cdots\cdot(n-1)^2\cdot n^1$$

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes referred to as the superfactorial of n (although there is at least one other function that's also called superfactorial), and its values are given by [OEIS sequence A000178](http://oeis.org/A000178). I don't believe there are any shortcuts to computing it, other than noting that $sf(n) = \prod_{1 \le i \lt j \le n}\left( j - i \right)$

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the asymptotic behavior of $\prod_{k=1}^n k! = \prod_{k=1}^n k^{n-k+1}$.

The standard way to estimate such things is by taking the logarithm. But in this case, we can get it directly from Stirling's approximation (which itself can be proved by taking logs).

[Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) states $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$.

Thus $\prod_{k=1}^n k! \sim (2\pi)^n \sqrt{n!} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n k^k}{e^{n(n+1)/2}}$

So now we just need to estimate $\prod_{k=1}^n k^k$. We could go do this, but even better is to use:

$\prod_{k=1}^n k! \prod_{k=1}^n k^k = \prod_{k=1}^n k^{n-k+1} \prod_{k=1}^n k^k = \prod_{k=1}^n k^{n+1} = (n!)^{n+1}$

Thus $(\prod_{k=1}^n k!)^2 \sim (2\pi)^n \sqrt{n!} \frac{(n!)^{n+1}}{e^{n(n+1)/2}}$

Then we get, applying Stirling's approximation to $\sqrt{n!}$ and $(n!)^{n+1}$:

$(\prod_{k=1}^n k!)^2 \sim (2\pi)^{2n+3/2}n^{3/4 + n/2}e^{-n(n+1)/2-n/2-n(n+1)} n^{n(n+1)}$

Thus $\prod_{k=1}^n k! \sim (2\pi)^{n+3/4} e^{-3n^2/4 - n} n^{n^2/2 + 3n/4 + 3/8}$