# Computing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}i!\right)^{1\over n^{2}} (n^{x})\right] $ if exists for certain $x\in\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

I came across this problem on my exam and even after three hours of trying I am not able to get through the problem.

I think it can be expressed as the limit of a sum but I am not sure and all my attempts to do the same have failed.

**Question:**

> If the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}i!\right)^{\frac{1}{n^2}} (n^{x})\right]$$ exists and is finite what are the possible values of $x$ and the corresponding values of limit?

I got something like $$e^{\ln{1\over n}\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n\left[1-{r-1\over n}\ln\left({r\over n}\right)\right]}$$ but I am having trouble with that r-1 over there.

Can this be expressed as a Riemann sum?

(So recently all the answers I have got seem to be skipping steps I get that all these people are professional in their own fields but can you please try to write answers for someone who has considerably low IQ than yourself, thanks for the same)

Comment: Have you tried something like $y=e^{\ln y}$? Then note that the first parenthesis can be written as $1^n\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot...\cdot(n-1)^2\cdot n$

Comment: @Andrei  Yes indeed I have but then I got something like ${1 \over n}\sum_{r=1}^n [1-{r-1\over n} ln({r\over n})] $

Comment: That r-1 is what is bugging me. Shouldn't it be r

Comment: It will not matter in the limit $n\to\infty$. When $n$ is large, small $r$ will not count, and for large enough $r$, you have $r-1\approx r$.

Comment: @Andrei Can you justify this rigorously?

Comment: I might be able to, but you don't need to. Just split that term into $\frac rn\ln\frac rn-\frac 1n\ln\frac rn$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106094/discussion-between-hrishabh-nayal-and-andrei).

Comment: Btw that $r-1$ does not cause any problem. You can chose different tags for different components while forming a Riemann sum. A more general principle allows us to do so. Check [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3081325/72031).

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Thanks for the link but I do not think I have enough knowledge to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Riemann sum is convergent, that means that the left Riemann sum limit is the same as the right Riemann sum limit. That means $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r-1}n\ln\frac{r-1}n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}n\ln\frac{r}n$$
Now just use the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), since each term in $\frac{r-1}{n}\ln\frac rn$ is between the corresponding terms in the left and right Riemann sums.

Comment: Great! Just one thing what is left and right reimann sum?

Comment: Your sum formula counts the larger numbers more than the smaller ones. The factorial formula weights the smaller numbers more: $n$ shows up once, $n-1$ shows up twice, ... $2$ shows up $n-1$ times and $1$ shows up $n$ times.

Comment: @HrishabhNayal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum. You draw rectangles on each small interval. The height of the rectangle is either the function on the left end or the right end. The integral must be the same in the limit $n\to\infty$

Comment: @robjohn Correct. The full sum should have been $\frac{n-(r-1)}n\ln\frac rn$. You can split this into two sums, one for $\ln\frac rn$ and one for the sum that the question was about

Answer (score 5):

**Asymptotic Expansion via Riemann Sum**

Compute the log of the product as a Riemann Sum
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k\log(n-k+1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\left(\log\left(1-\frac{k}{n}+\frac1n\right)+\log(n)\right)\frac1n\tag{1a}\\
&\sim\int_0^1x\log(1-x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac12\log(n)\tag{1b}\\
&=\int_0^1\log(1-x)\,\mathrm{d}\frac{x^2-1}2+\frac12\log(n)\tag{1c}\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{x+1}2\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac12\log(n)\tag{1d}\\
&=\frac12\log(n)-\frac34\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the product is asymptotically
$$
\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk!\right)^{1/n^2}\sim e^{-3/4}n^{1/2}\tag2
$$
Therefore, for $x=-1/2$, the limit comes to
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk!\right)^{1/n^2}n^{-1/2}=e^{-3/4}}\tag3
$$
For $x\lt-1/2$, the limit is $0$.

---

**Asymptotic Expansion via Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula**

As is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162426), we have asymptotically in $n$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-z}
=\zeta(z)+\frac{n^{1-z}}{1-z}+\frac12n^{-z}-\frac{z}{12}n^{-1-z}+O\left(\frac1{n^{3+z}}\right)\tag4
$$
applying $-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)k^{-z}
&=-\zeta'(z)+n^{1-z}\frac{(1-z)\log(n)-1}{(1-z)^2}+\frac12\log(n)n^{-z}\\
&-n^{-1-z}\frac{z\log(n)-1}{12}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^{3+z}}\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Setting $z=0$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)=\overbrace{\,\,-\zeta'(0)\ }^{\frac12\log(2\pi)}+n(\log(n)-1)+\frac12\log(n)+\frac1{12n}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^3}\right)\tag6
$$
Setting $z=-1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)k
&=\overbrace{-\zeta'(-1)}^{\log(A)-\frac1{12}}+n^2\frac{2\log(n)-1}4+\frac12n\log(n)+\frac{\log(n)+1}{12}\\
&+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)\tag7
\end{align}
$$
where $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1)\log(k)
&=n^2\frac{2\log(n)-3}4+n\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}en\right)+\frac5{12}\log(n)\\
&+\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{A}\right)+\frac1{12}+\frac1{12n}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)\tag8
\end{align}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^nk!=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{A}e^{1/12}\,\color{#C00}{n^{n^2/2}e^{-3n^2/4}}\color{#090}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}en\right)^n}n^{5/12}\color{#00F}{e^{\frac1{12n}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)}}\tag9
$$
Finally,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk!\right)^{1/n^2}=\color{#C00}{n^{1/2}e^{-3/4}}+\color{#090}{O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/2}}\right)}}\tag{10}
$$

---

**The Glaisher–Kinkelin Constant**

Equation $(6)$ is essentially Stirling's Formula:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^nk=\sqrt{2\pi}\,n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}\left(1+\frac1{12n}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\tag{11}
$$
where $\sqrt{2\pi}=e^{-\zeta'(0)}$. This shows that $\zeta'(0)=-\frac12\log(2\pi)$.

Equation $(7)$ says that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^nk^k=A\,n^{n^2/2+n/2+1/12}e^{-n^2/4}\left(1+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)\right)\tag{12}
$$
where $A=e^{\frac1{12}-\zeta'(-1)}$.

Just as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\log(n)+\gamma+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{13}
$$
is the defining limit for $\gamma$, the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), $(12)$ appears to be the defining limit for $A$, the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 
more accurate than needed estimate
from my answer at
[Formula for $1! \times 2! \times \cdots \times n!$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061589/formula-for-1-times-2-times-cdots-times-n/1061750#1061750):

$\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n} n!
\sim C^{1/2} (2\pi)^{3/8}n^{5/12}(2\pi)^{n/2}(n/e)^n
\left(\dfrac{n}{e^{3/2}}\right)^{n^2/2}
$
where
$C 
=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{n^{1/12}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(
\dfrac{k!}{\sqrt{2\pi k}(k/e)^k}
\right)
\approx 1.046335066770503
$.

Taking the $n^2$ root,
$\left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n} n!\right)^{1/n^2}
\to\left(\dfrac{n}{e^{3/2}}\right)^{1/2}
$
since all the other terms
go to $1$.

Comment: Wow that is amazing. That is one neat solution. Love it!

Comment: Note that $C = e^{2\zeta '( - 1)} (2\pi )^{1/4}$, where $\zeta$ is Riemann's zeta function.

Comment: @Gary: With your $C$, $C^{1/2}(2\pi)^{3/8}=2.1244594414121106650$, which is what I got in my answer. However, $C=1.1372658212289253252$ doesn't match the $C$ in this answer. This means that in my answer, $C_2=e^{\zeta'(-1)}\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: I obtained it from the fact that the product of factorials is $
n!G(n + 1)$, where $G$ is the Barnes $G$-function. The known asymptotics of $G(n+1)$ and $n!$ yields the asymptotics of the product with the constant I gave (it is related to the Glaisher--Kinkelin constant). The ratio of my $C$ and marty cohen's $C$ is $e^{1/12}$.

Comment: @Gary: I have improved my approach using another answer which approximates the zeta function using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula. The constants are in terms of $\zeta'(0)$ and $\zeta'(-1)$, which are given in terms of $\pi$ and $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If we take logarithm of sequence in question we get another sequence $$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log k! +xn^2\log n\right)\tag{1}$$ Applying Cesaro-Stolz we can see that limit of $a_n$ is same as that of $$\frac{1} {2n-1}\left(\log n! +xn^2\log n-x(n-1)^2\log n-x(n-1)^2\log(1-1/n)\right) $$ provided the limit of above exists. The above expression has the same limit as that of $$\frac{1}{2n-1}(\log n! +2nx\log n)+\frac{x}{2}\tag{2}$$

---

We can now use Stirling approximation which says that $$\log n! - \left(n\log n - n+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi n) \right) \to 0$$ which implies that $$\frac{1}{2n-1}(\log n! - n\log n+n) \to 0$$ Now expression $(2)$ can be rewritten as $$\frac{\log n! - n\log n+n} {2n-1}+(1+2x)\frac{n\log n}{2n-1}-\frac{n}{2n-1}+\frac {x} {2}$$ Clearly the first term tends to $0$ and the last two terms have a finite limit $(x-1)/2$. The second term has a finite limit only when $x=-1/2$. If $x<-1/2$ the expression in $(2)$ tends to $-\infty $ and if $x>-1/2$ the expression tends to $\infty$.

It follows that the limit in question exists if $x\leq - 1/2$. If $x<-1/2$ then the desired limit is $0$ and if $x=-1/2$ then the desired limit is $e^{(x-1)/2}=e^{-3/4}$.

---

Another alternative is to apply Cesaro-Stolz on first term in $(2)$. Doing this gives us the expression $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\log n+2xn\log n-2x(n-1)\log n-2x(n-1)\log(1-1/n)\right)$$ which has same limit as that of $$\frac{1+2x}{2}\log n+x$$ and the conclusion is same as obtained earlier. This approach avoids complicated Stirling formula.

Comment: Can you explain how you used Cesaro-Stolz in second step.  i. e how you wrote in form of sequence ${a_{n+1}-a_n \over b_{n+1}-b_n}$?

Comment: @HrishabhNayal, for the expression above the _Stirling's approximation_, you have $\log(n-1)=\log\left(n\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=\log n+\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$,  while $\log(n!)-\log((n-1)!)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log i=\log n$

Comment: Or just $\log\left(\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\right)=\log n$

Comment: @ ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Thanks! I see it now