# Is my asymptotic formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\log(k!)$ right?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, solution-verification, asymptotics

Today I tried to derive an asymptotic formula for the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\log(k!)$$
Here is what I did: This can be rewritten as $$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{1<n\le k}\log n$$
Now I applied the Euler summation formula, and this turned to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(\int_{1}^{k}\log t\,dt+\int_{1}^{k}\frac{t-[t]}{t}dt+\log(k)([k]-k)\right)$$
$\int_{1}^{k}\frac{t-[t]}{t}dt$ is dominated by $\int_{1}^{k}\frac{1}{t}dt=\log k$, so $\int_{1}^{k}\frac{t-[t]}{t}dt=O(\log k)$, and it is also true that $\log(k)([k]-k)=O(\log k)$
Now, the sum becomes
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}(1-k+k\log k+O(\log k)+O(\log k))=\sum_{k=1}^{m}(1-k+k\log k+O(\log k))$$
which is equal to
$$m-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}+\log H(m)+O(\log m)$$
where $H(m)$ is [hyperfactorial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperfactorial#:%7E:text=hyperfactorial%20(plural%20hyperfactorials),1%20*%204%20*%2027%20%3D%20108). Is my solution right? I could have made a mistake.

Comment: See http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/CLASS/HANDOUTS/factorialasymp.pdf

Comment: @TheSimpliFire oh thanks. But they gave some other asymptotic. In fact, mine is better than theirs.

Comment: In terms of the Barnes-$G$ function and the gamma function, your sum is $
\log G(m + 2) = \log G(m + 1) + \log \Gamma(m) +\log m
$. You can use the known asymptotic expansions http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.17.E5 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E1 to derive a complete asymptotic expansion for large $m$.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k!)=(n+1)\log(n!)-\log(H(n))$$ exactly.

Comment: @robjohn oh thanks. I also derived another asymptotic formula whose error term is improved to $O(1)$, and that formula does **not** contain hyperfactorial, so it is very easy to compute it. Even easier than this exact formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment on the Answer in the Question**

One problem is that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^mO(\log(k))=O(m\log(m))\tag1
$$
However, as the result is $\sim\frac{m^2}2\log(m)$, this does not invalidate the entire result.

Equation $(7)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3601221) shows that
$$
\begin{align}
\log(H(m))
&=\sum_{k=1}^mk\log(k)\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{m^2}2\log(m)-\frac{m^2}4+O(m\log(m))\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
so we get
$$
m-\frac{m(m+1)}2+\log(H(m))=\frac{m^2}2\log(m)-\frac{3m^2}4+O(m\log(m))\tag3
$$
Thus, as long as the error term is taken to be $O(m\log(m))$ instead of $O(\log(m))$, your answer is correct.

---

**More Precise Asymptotic Expansion**

Using a result from an earlier answer,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k!)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k\log(j)\tag{4a}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\log(j)\tag{4b}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(n-j+1)\log(j)\tag{4c}\\
&=n^2\frac{2\log(n)-3}4+n\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}en\right)+\frac5{12}\log(n)\\
&+\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{A}\right)+\frac1{12}+\frac1{12n}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)\tag{4d}\\
&=\frac{n^2}2\log(n)-\frac{3n^2}4+n\log(n)+\left(\frac12\log(2\pi)-1\right)n+\frac5{12}\log(n)\\
&+\left(\frac1{12}+\frac12\log(2\pi)-\log(A)\right)+\frac1{12n}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)\tag{4e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: definition of $n!$
$\text{(4b)}$: change order of summation
$\text{(4c)}$: evaluate the inner sum
$\text{(4d)}$: $(8)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3601221), where $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant)
$\text{(4e)}$: rearranging terms

By taking more terms in the Euler-Maclaurin expansions of $(6)$ and $(7)$ from [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3601221) cited above, we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k!)\\
&=\frac12n^2\log(n)-\frac34n^2+n\log(n)+\left(\frac12\log(2\pi)-1\right)n+\frac5{12}\log(n)\\
&+\left(\frac1{12}+\frac12\log(2\pi)-\log(A)\right)+\frac1{12n}-\frac1{240n^2}-\frac1{360n^3}+\frac1{1008n^4}\\
&+\frac1{1260n^5}-\frac1{1440n^6}-\frac1{1680n^7}+\frac1{1056n^8}+\frac1{1188n^9}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{10}}\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Woah! This is so good! Very very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gary commented
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\log(k!)=\log \big[G(m+2)\big]$$ Using a CAS,
$$\log \big[G(m+2)\big]=\frac1{12}(6 m^2+12 m+5)\log(m)+m \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi }}{e}\right)-\frac 34m^2+$$ $$\log \left(\frac{ \sqrt{2 \pi e^{\frac 16} }}{A}\right)+\frac 1{12m}-\frac{1}{240 m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)$$ which shows a relative error lower than $0.01$% as soon as $m>1$

Comment: Oh very thanks. Btw, I derived it myself. The main question is asking to verify mine. But still, thanks.

Comment: $A\approx 1.28243$ is Glaisher constant such that $\log (A)=\frac{1}{12}-\zeta '(-1)$

Comment: @LeonhardEuler. Your is not bad at all. The idea of the hyperfactorial is good. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh wow. Thanks.

Comment: (+1) my answer agrees with your CAS (which one did you use?)

Comment: @robjohn.  Impressive answer ! I used Mathematica.